# MySQL - separate tables or combined table for users and service providers

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am trying to create a database. We have mobile apps that work similar to UBER.

We have normal users installing the application and Service Providers with another app to answer to the bookings of users.

The database i am using is MySQL.

My question is, which architectural design is better?

- 2 Tables

  - `users`
  - `serviceProviders`
- 1 table to hold both users and service providers, with a `type` column to differentiate between them

It should be noted that both tables will have half same fields like phone, address, name , status etc. While half columns will be different.

So, which option is better and why?

Comment: Different entities (= different things) => different tables!

Answer (score 0):

You almost certainly want to have two distinct tables.

First, you note that half the columns related to users and to service providers are the same (contact information and the like), and half are different. In many cases, even unused columns do take up space in your database; designing a table such that 1/3 of the columns in each row will always be NULL (or at least unused) doesn't particularly seem like a good stating point for a design. (Other considerations, like performance, could cause you to change that, but I'd prefer to have my initial design be laid out logically, and modify it as needed from there).

Second, while both entities will have some common aspects (some sort of user ID/account, probably some sort of password for security purposes, etc.), beyond that it seems safe to assume that they will be very different. Most other tables where you would use those IDs are likely to explicitly want users (history of their use of the service, preferences) or service providers (log of customer interaction, possibly time-keeping information). In fact, it sounds like you have two separate actual applications, one available just to users, and one just for service providers; this would imply a sharp division of permissions (users should not be able to log onto the service provider app, period).

You will probably want to use the IDs for users and service providers as foreign keys. By keeping the two entities in separate tables, you guarantee that you'll never accidentally assign a user ID where a service provider ID should have gone, and vice versa.

Now, you would have the option of creating a third table, `account`. This would hold those common columns from `users` and `serviceproviders`, possibly including their login credentials for getting into the apps. Both the `users` and the `serviceproviders` tables would have an `account_id` column linking them to the correct account. This might be seen as particularly valuable if you want to allow someone who is both a service provider *and* a user of the service to be able to use a single set of credentials.

That said: I personally would *not* use an `account` table. The theoretical person who is both a service provider and a user could presumably create a user account and a service provider account using the same credentials themselves, if they wanted to. A person who stops being a service provider but continues to be a user would need their access to the service provider application revoked. However, you'd want to retain their personal information, and to allow them to keep using the service. If this individual has a single `account` record for both roles, then you can't (for example) just change their password to disable their access, or mark the account as disabled, as this would affect their ability to continue to be a regular user.

For that matter, much to the likely data (address, phone number, etc.) for a service provider who is also a user would be likely to be different across the two accounts. For a user account, someone might list a personal phone number, email address, and a home street address; whereas, for the service provider account, they'd be more likely (and should probably be encouraged to) use their work phone, email, and office address.

There are workarounds, and if you *know* for certain that all service providers will/must also be users, and *want* them to provide the same information, then the `account` table may make more sense (on the basis of minimizing redundant information stored in the DB).

However, again, for the initial design, I would probably keep things separate. Having the same columns in multiple tables isn't the same as having the same data in multiple places.